# Dell Photo 924 AIO printer not being detected

Tags: 12.04, printing

I am wondering if anyone knows any tricks to get a Dell Photo 924 printer to work with Ubuntu 12.04?

I've tried a couple dozen drivers within Ubuntu, none have worked. I've googled for a few hours with no luck with any method I found and tried.

I have the driver disc which also didn't work. I'll be grateful for any directions I can get with this.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer, but a hint could be that most of the Dell printers are rebranded Cannon's. Might be an outside shot if you could figure out what is the closest model to t

Comment: Thanks Mordoc, I will try the Cannon drivers.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: @rockSteady did it work?